# Marking Test case status in Testopia

Tags: automation, automated-tests, bugzilla

I had a requirement to mark the automated test cases in Testopia based on the results of the automated test cases. How can I do this? I had the testopia API code, but I am not able to find a solution for this.

Comment: What's main problem about your automation? Recently, I also do some integration work between Jenkins and Testopia for automation.

Comment: I hadn't been using Jenkins. The automated test case must be marked as Failed in Testopia on failure. At First, we were unable to use XMLRPC from java as it is not supporting Cookies. We had modified the API of j2Bugzilla in flow with Testopia

Comment: I am using the python version of testopia XMLRPC api. from [here](http://bzr.mozilla.org/bugzilla/extensions/testopia/trunk/annotate/head:/extensions/Testopia/contrib/drivers/python/testopia.py) It works well.

Comment: I can't migrate my complete framework to python since I specified I was using java

Comment: [testopia-java-driver](https://github.com/kinow/testopia-java-driver) How about this?

Comment: I didn't tried this & don't need it as I had already made use of J2Bugzilla

Comment: It seems that J2Bugzilla is only for Bugzilla rather than testpoia.

Comment: It is for Bugzilla . We had modified in such a way, that it is useful for both bugzilla & Testopia

Answer (score 3):

The Testopia Plugin for Jenkins v1.1 is available now. This wiki explains how it works:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Testopia+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

I used the perl example from the Testopia contrib directory. I called this from a shell script and this updates the status of the testcase.

Recently I got involved in a project to develop a plugin for Jenkins to do the same.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Testopia+Plugin

Comment: We were using java to develop our scripts & the result status of a test  case is a java variable. Can u be clear with the above message